# Haskell Chat Server Tutorial on haskell.org Not Working

Tags: sockets, haskell, tcp

I'm trying to follow the tutorial to create a chat server on [haskell.org](https://wiki.haskell.org/Implement_a_chat_server), but I keep getting this error:

```
app/Main.hs:19:32: error:
    Variable not in scope: iNADDR_ANY :: HostAddress
   |
19 |   bind sock (SockAddrInet 4242 iNADDR_ANY)
```

I tried seeing if the issue was dependency related, but I included Network as a dependency and imported Network.Socket. I double checked the documentation for Network.Socket, and it's shown [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-2.6.2.1/docs/src/Network-Socket.html#iNADDR_ANY).

Comment: It looks like that was deprecated in network-2.x and then removed in network-3.x. I guess the tutorial is out of date. You might try to specify `build-depends: network < 3` in your cabal file. Otherwise, you need to adapt to the new 3.x API. I've never used it so I don't know much more.

Comment: Keep in mind that many pages on wiki.haskell.org are outdated. There are some pearls on there, but it is a very mixed bag. I'd be especially wary of concrete tutorials like the one you link.